# Base64 encoding an image alerts correct, response is nil

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I'm trying to encode an image in Base64 from a URL.

```
function getBase64Image(url) {
  var img = new Image(),
      response = '';

  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    response = dataURL;
    alert(response);
  };

  img.src = url;
  return response;
}
```

The `alert()` works fine but the response is nil:

[image: alert]

You can see in the console in the screenshot if I `log` the response like so (it's done twice in the screenshot) it returns nothing:

```
console.log(getBase64Image('<%= asset_path "test.jpg" %>'));
```

Obviously we can read the image because the alert has the encoding. What am I missing?

**Update**

Relevant JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guxzxq20/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach: Canvas

Load the image into an Image-Object, paint it to a non-tainted canvas and convert the canvas back to a dataURL.

```
function convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas(url, callback, outputFormat) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
    canvas = null;
  };
  img.src = url;
}
```

call method

```
convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png',function(response){
 alert(response)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are returning the empty `response` object that you have created, because the `response` object inside the `onLoad()` function is not accessing the outside `response`.

Try changing your code to calling a callback once the `onload()` function reaches its end, and using that callback to alert.
Something like:

```
function getBase(url, callback) {
    // ... code

    img.onload = function () {
        // ... code

        callback(response);
    }
}
```

This was a very raw example.

Comment: That definitely helped _slightly_, I've only got `data:,` returning though.

Comment: Can you upload your code into a jsfiddle? I can help you then.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/guxzxq20/4/ try that and tell me if that code works. I can't test it on jsfiddle because of Cross Origin stuff.